# Unable to create a window using kivy 1.11.1 and python 3.7.0

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

**I am trying to create a simple program using kivy. The program runs without errors, however, no window appears. Here are the steps I followed for installing kivy:**

python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv

python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*

python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*

python -m pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.1.*

python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1

python -m pip install kivy_examples==1.11.1

**This is the program that I'm trying to run:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App): 
  def build(self): 
    label = Label(text = 'Hello from kivy',size_hint = (.5,.5),pos_hint {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5})
    return label


if __name__ == " main" :
  app = MainApp()
  app.run() #App class contains run() - sets up the graphics
```

**And this is the output I'm getting:**

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Ayesha.kivy\logs\kivy_19-12-22_0.txt

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Ayesha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy__init__.py"

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]

[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Ayesha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe"

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because there is no `MainApp` class defined.

Comment: Also " main" should be `"__main__"`.

Comment: I didn't realize I wrote MainApp instead of MyApp. My program is working now...thanks a lot!